# Send html table in outlook mail via Python

Tags: html, python-2.7, pandas, outlook, win32com

I have a code which uses win32com to open Outlook and send mail. 
I am trying to send a table which is in myexample.html file to a recipient. 
However when I use

```
msg.body=open('myexample.html').read()
```

This is what comes in the mail that I've sent

```
table border="1" class="dataframe"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr style="text-align: right;"> 
      <th>DG Lead</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody> 
    <tr> 
      <td>Krishnamurthy Ramamurthy</td> 
      <td>324</td> 
> 
    <tr>
```

But I want a table view of this. 
How can I get that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python) and [Send table as an email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275467/send-table-as-an-email-body-not-attachment-in-python)

Comment: Hey, I figured the answer to it. 
Just had to alter a line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer to it. 
Just need to alter

```
msg.body = body
```

to

```
msg.HTMLBody  = body
```