# Python Pandas to_html styling

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, email

I am trying to translate a csv into an html table, insert it into an email and send it out. I found a similar question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275467/send-table-as-an-email-body-not-attachment-in-python) and seems to work great.

My email is sending out but no matter what I do I cannot seem to style the table. Ideally I want to add a colored title to the table and possible modify the borders. This is going to be something that is automatically sent every week so I want it as automated as possible.

```
with open('fileTest.html', 'r') as f:
    x = f.read()
f.close()
html = x

with open('testy.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

#text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html, 'html')])
```

This is and example of the code I have, the full version is basically the same as the answer in the link I shared.

If I try to add a style tag to the top of the file then the `.format()` errors out with a key error.

***EDIT***

I should mention that I am generating my html from pandas `to_html`

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import HTML
df = pd.read_csv('testy.csv')
df.to_html('fileTest.html')
```

I have also tried it this way:

```
HTML(df.to_html(filetest.html))
```

Here is an example of the first couple rows of output

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>Name of Region</th>
      <th>Number Sent To</th>
      <th>YTD Calls</th>
      <th>MTD Calls</th>
      <th>Week of</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Windham</td>
      <td>18032515985</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
```

[Here is](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html)  a link to the docs on styling them. But I find them lacking

Answer (score 1):

Instead using `to_html` styling, use `style`.

```
import pandas as pd

def style_line(s):
    '''Rendering odd and even rows with different color'''
    return ['background-color: #D4E6F1' if i%2!=0 else 'background-color: #85C1E9' for i in range(len(s))]


df = pd.read_csv('testy.csv')
# df.to_html('fileTest.html')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.style.apply(style_line).render()
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))` line, why not do something like:

```
style = '''
<style>
    #headings {
    font-size:26px !important;
    line-height:32px !important;
    }
</style>
'''

html = style + str(html)
message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html, 'html')])
```

This should style your table.

Comment: Tried it out and it had no effect on the table

Comment: Yea, I will edit it in. I also did more research and I am going to modify my question because I left something out that can help. I am generating my html with pandas `to_html` method. I think there is a way to style this but can't figure it out