# Add borders of table sent by email via Python

Tags: python, html, email, smtplib

Currently I use this solution [Send table as an email body (not attachment ) in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275467/send-table-as-an-email-body-not-attachment-in-python) for sending tables in emails via Python:

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTPException
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate

text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""

with open('result.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)

text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))

message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])

message['Subject'] = "Your data"
message['From'] = 'a@abc.com'
message['To'] = 'b@abc.com'

sender = "a@abc.com"
receivers = ['b@abc.com']

try:
    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('mail.abc.com')
    smtp_obj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message.as_string())         
    print ("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
    print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Data is loaded from csv file. But I need to add borders to the table to make it look like pandas DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full solution of creating the table with borders.

```
table = '' 
with open('result.csv') as csvFile: 
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')    
    table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td class="cell">{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames])) 
    for row in reader:  
        table_row = '<tr>' 
        for fn in reader.fieldnames:            
            table_row += '<td class="cell">{}</td>'.format(row[fn]) 
        table_row += '</tr>' 
        table += table_row


html = """
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>html title</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
table{
    background-color: #000000;
    empty-cells:hide;
  Border:5px solid red;
 }
 td.cell{
    background-color: white;
 }

</style>
</head>
<html><body><p>Hi!</p>
<p>Here is your data.</p>
<table style="border: black 0.5px;"> 
%s 
</table>
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Python 3.5</p>
</body></html>""" % table


message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(html,'html')])


message['Subject'] = "Some stats via mail"
message['From'] = 'a@abc.com'
message['To'] = 'b@abc.com'

sender = "a@abc.com"
receivers = ['b@abc.com']

try:
    smtp_obj = smtplib.SMTP('mail.abc.com')
    smtp_obj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message.as_string())         
    print ("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
    print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Answer (score 10):

Add style to the original html script will work.

```
html = """
<html>
<head>
<style> 
  table, th, td {{ border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; }}
  th, td {{ padding: 5px; }}
</style>
</head>
<body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
email_content = """
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>html title</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
table{
    background-color: #AAD373;
    empty-cells:hide;
  Border:5px solid red;
 }
 td.cell{
    background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="border: blue 1px solid;">
<tr><td class="cell">Cell 1.1</td><td class="cell">Cell 1.2</td></tr>
<tr><td class="cell">Cell 2.1</td><td class="cell"></td></tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thank you! But cat I somehow load the table from csv, not writing explicitly 
the content of every single cell?

Comment: Did not get !! you want to add the content values from CSV ?? mean values in table cells ?? if that you can ,

Comment: Reading Data From CSV use that my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')

Comment: If you suppose `numpy.genfromtxt`, it doesn't work. Although, I don't know what part exactly you wanted to replace with that code.

Comment: It giving any error or what ?? can you share the code how you reading CSV File

Comment: `np.genfromtxt('result.csv', delimiter=';')` gives `array([ nan,  nan])`. The csv file is same as before.

Comment: import csv

       table = ''
      with open(csv_path, encoding="utf8") as csvFile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    table = '<tr>{}</tr>'.format(''.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(header) for header in reader.fieldnames]))
    for row in reader:
        table_row = '<tr>'
        for fn in reader.fieldnames:
            table_row += '<td>{}<\td>'.format(row[fn])
        table_row += '<\tr>'
        table += table_row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158406/discussion-between-anastasia-manokhina-and-muhammad-ali).

Comment: I am new here , and i think we can not chat , for chat we need REPUTATION100