# Copy and format excel table to outlook body using python

Tags: python, html, email, smtplib

I am trying to send an outlook email with content from a excel file pasted in the message body of outlook email. **I have to use `smtplib` only**

I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275467/send-table-as-an-email-body-not-attachment-in-python) shown below

```
import csv
from tabulate import tabulate
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
me = 'user2@org.com'
server = 'internal-server:25'
you = 'user1@org.com'
text = """
Hello, Friend.

Here is your data:

{table}

Regards,

Me"""

html = """
<html><body><p>Hello, Friend.</p>
<p>Here is your data:</p>
{table}
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Me</p>
</body></html>
""" 
with open('input.csv') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    data = list(reader)
text = text.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="grid"))
html = html.format(table=tabulate(data, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
message = MIMEMultipart(
    "alternative", None, [MIMEText(text), MIMEText(html,'html')])
message['Subject'] = "Your data"
message['From'] = me
message['To'] = you
server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
server.ehlo()
server.sendmail(me, you, message.as_string())
server.quit()
```

However, it prints the table as below (without table grid lines and format)

[image]

I expect my output to be like as shown below (as a table and not as a image in outlook body)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to add a `border=1` attribute to your `table` HTML element. Sadly, `tabulate` doesn't support such a thing. One way to add the `border` attribute is to skip `tabulate.tabulate` and write your own table formatter like so:

```
def html_tabulate(table):
    table_it = iter(table)
    result = []
    result.append("<table border=1>")
    result.append("<thead>")
    headers = next(table_it)
    result.append("<tr><th>" + "</th><th>".join(headers) + "</th></tr>")
    result.append("</thead>")
    for row in table_it:
        result.append("<tr><td>" + "</td><td>".join(row) + "</td></tr>")
    result.append("</table>")
    return "\n".join(result)
```

and then use your new function when you create the HTML for your emaill:

```
html = html.format(table=html_tabulate(data))
```

Comment: Hi, I am encountering another related problem in smtplib text message. would you be interested to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71709672/how-to-send-a-complete-email-using-smtplib-python